# Generating multiple strings by replacing wildcards

Tags: python, regex, string, replace, wildcard

So i have the following strings:

```
"xxxxxxx#FUS#xxxxxxxx#ACS#xxxxx"
"xxxxx#3#xxxxxx#FUS#xxxxx"
```

And i want to generate the following strings from this pattern (i'll use the second example):
Considering #FUS# will represent 2.

```
"xxxxx0xxxxxx0xxxxx"  
"xxxxx0xxxxxx1xxxxx"    
"xxxxx0xxxxxx2xxxxx"

"xxxxx1xxxxxx0xxxxx"  
"xxxxx1xxxxxx1xxxxx"    
"xxxxx1xxxxxx2xxxxx"

"xxxxx2xxxxxx0xxxxx"  
"xxxxx2xxxxxx1xxxxx"    
"xxxxx2xxxxxx2xxxxx"

"xxxxx3xxxxxx0xxxxx"  
"xxxxx3xxxxxx1xxxxx"    
"xxxxx3xxxxxx2xxxxx"
```

Basically if i'm given a string as above, i want to generate multiple strings by replacing the wildcards that can be #FUS#, #WHATEVER# or with a number #20# and generating multiple strings with the ranges that those wildcards represent.

I've managed to get a regex to find the wildcards.

```
wildcardRegex = f"(#FUS#|#WHATEVER#|#([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9])#)"
```

Which finds correctly the target wildcards.

For 1 wildcard present, it's easy.

```
re.sub()
```

For more it gets complicated. Or maybe it was a long day...

But i think my algorithm logic is failing hard because i'm failing to write some code that will basically generate the signals. I think i need some kind of recursive function that will be called for each number of wildcards present (up to maybe 4 can be present (xxxxx#2#xxx#2#xx#FUS#xx#2#x)).

I need a list of resulting signals.

Is there any easy way to do this that I'm completely missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re

stringV1 = "xxx#FUS#xxxxi#3#xxx#5#xx"
stringV2 = "XXXXXXXXXX#FUS#XXXXXXXXXX#3#xxxxxx#5#xxxx"

regex = "(#FUS#|#DSP#|#([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9])#)"

WILDCARD_FUS = "#FUS#"
RANGE_FUS = 3

def getSignalsFromWildcards(app, can):
    sigList = list()
    if WILDCARD_FUS in app:
        for i in range(RANGE_FUS):
            outAppSig = app.replace(WILDCARD_FUS, str(i), 1)
            outCanSig = can.replace(WILDCARD_FUS, str(i), 1)
            if "#" in outAppSig:
                newSigList = getSignalsFromWildcards(outAppSig, outCanSig)
                sigList += newSigList
            else:
                sigList.append((outAppSig, outCanSig))

    elif len(re.findall("(#([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9])#)", stringV1)) > 0:
        wildcard = re.search("(#([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9])#)", app).group()
        tarRange = int(wildcard.strip("#"))
        for i in range(tarRange):
            outAppSig = app.replace(wildcard, str(i), 1)
            outCanSig = can.replace(wildcard, str(i), 1)
            if "#" in outAppSig:
                newSigList = getSignalsFromWildcards(outAppSig, outCanSig)
                sigList += newSigList
            else:
                sigList.append((outAppSig, outCanSig))
    return sigList

if "#" in stringV1:
    resultList = getSignalsFromWildcards(stringV1, stringV2)

for item in resultList:
    print(item)
```

results in

```
('xxx0xxxxi0xxxxx', 'XXXXXXXXXX0XXXXXXXXXX0xxxxxxxxxx')
('xxx0xxxxi1xxxxx', 'XXXXXXXXXX0XXXXXXXXXX1xxxxxxxxxx')
('xxx0xxxxi2xxxxx', 'XXXXXXXXXX0XXXXXXXXXX2xxxxxxxxxx')
('xxx1xxxxi0xxxxx', 'XXXXXXXXXX1XXXXXXXXXX0xxxxxxxxxx')
('xxx1xxxxi1xxxxx', 'XXXXXXXXXX1XXXXXXXXXX1xxxxxxxxxx')
('xxx1xxxxi2xxxxx', 'XXXXXXXXXX1XXXXXXXXXX2xxxxxxxxxx')
('xxx2xxxxi0xxxxx', 'XXXXXXXXXX2XXXXXXXXXX0xxxxxxxxxx')
('xxx2xxxxi1xxxxx', 'XXXXXXXXXX2XXXXXXXXXX1xxxxxxxxxx')
('xxx2xxxxi2xxxxx', 'XXXXXXXXXX2XXXXXXXXXX2xxxxxxxxxx')
```

long day after-all...